# Can I get Friends Of Friends of a User using Google+ API?

Tags: google-api, google-plus

I know that I can get a list of all the people in the users circles (where the user is the person who is using my app, who logged in using the G+ button.)

Is it possible to get that users friends friends? Like for each person in the users circles, can I get a list of people in their circle?

Comment: I am not sure if this question is about development or programming.

Answer (score 0):

No. You can only get a list of people circled by the currently authenticated user.